# Html in chrome console is different from html in browser...how is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

From a form, I stored in variables some values from input fields and in jquery using .html() I built a table like this:

```
var name = $('#name').val();
var age = $('#age').val();

$('table tbody').html('
<tr id="uniqueId">
<td id="name">name</td>
<td id="age">age</td>
</tr>'
)
```

Then I need to update the table, so I changed the data, I stored again the input field values in variables and with jquery I tried to replace the table with the new values like this:

```
$('#uniqueId').html('
   <tr id="uniqueId">
   <td id="name">NewName</td>
   <td id="age">NewAge</td>
   </tr>'
)
```

Something strange happened: html in the browser doesn't change, but if I look at chrome console, html is changed! I mean if I write in the console $('#uniqueId') it shows me the updated html, but if I use 'inspect' in the chrome console I can see just the old code.

Again: if I write in the console $('#uniqueId').html('HI'), the result is correct in the console, but nothing changes in the browser O_o

What's happened?! I tried to stored the new html code in another variable and then replace the old code like this:

```
var newCode = 'html code';
$('#uniqueId').html(newCode);
```

with no result..any idea?

Comment: I'm curious as to how this Javascript even works (if it does?), being that you're using single quotes to open the `.html()`, and then also for declaring the ID's within. You'd need to replace all of your `id='uniqueid'`, etc, with `id="uniqueid"`, or, do `.html("` instead of `.html('`. I'm a bit unclear on your issue but I wouldn't be surprised if this is related.

Comment: no the code is ok, I wrote too much fast the code when I posted the question...now I'm going to edit the code

Comment: @Stormhashe aside from the fact that if you use _the same_ quotes, you are writing invalid code, since you're closing a string, instead of writing an opening quote inside of the string.

Comment: @Stormhashe ...you're misunderstanding. Doing `.html('This isn't valid');` won't work, because the single-quote in "isn't" ends the string. All you have to do is look at the syntax highlighting to see what I mean. Also, razer, you're doing `.val()` for `#name` and `#age`, but those are `<td>`. These use `.html()` or `.text()`, *not* `.val()`.

Comment: Not sure if it will fix your issue, but you're inserting a `<tr>` tag inside a `<tr>` tag. When you select you uniqueId, you're selecting a table row. You are then setting the innerHTML equal to another table row. Therefore your final markup will be `<tr><tr> ... blah ... </tr></tr>`. No matter what the solution, this will result in some f-ed up markup on your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues that I'm noticing here.

**1.** You're using single quotes both for `.html(' ... ');`, and to declare the ID's within. Change it to `.html(" ... ")` instead.

**2.** Take a look at these lines in your first snippet...

```
var name = $('#name').val();
var age = $('#age').val();

<td id="name">name</td>
<td id="age">age</td>
```

`<td>` elements do not have a `.val()` property and should be referenced with `.html()`. That being said, you mentioned that you are getting the values from *inputs*. If that's the case, does this mean that you have duplicate element ID's?

**3.** Check out your snippet...

```
$('#uniqueId').html('
   <tr id="uniqueId">
   <td id="name">NewName</td>
   <td id="age">NewAge</td>
   </tr>'
)
```

This is going to cause issues. You're not only inserting a `<tr>` into a `<tr>`, but they have the same ID. I think you should be doing...

```
$('#uniqueId').html('
   <td id="name">NewName</td>
   <td id="age">NewAge</td>'
)
```

Comment: ok thank you very much man, I did a lot of mistakes with quotes and IDs...

Answer (score 0):

Your `uniqueId` might not be that 'unique' after all. Check that you only have a single ID in your whole HTML markup. Also, just for testing purposes, don't select by id, but by class name. If that works, then you undeniably have multiple 'unique' ids.

Answer (score -1):

Your javascript code is wrong. First on the declaration:

```
$('table tbody').html("<tr id='uniqueId'>" +
"<td id='name'>Name</td>" + 
"<td id='age'>Age</td>" +
"</tr>"
)
```

And then on the function:

```
$('#uniqueId').html("<tr id='uniqueId'> +
   "<td id='name'>NewName</td>" +
   "<td id='age'>NewAge</td>" +
   "</tr>'"
);
```